# IntelliSense with commonJS won't enable auto-completion on the arguments from Playwright fixture

Tags: visual-studio-code, playwright

When using  Playwright fixture properties as argument in the test functions, VS Code does not show the auto-completion picklist. For example, when I instantiate the UI map page class via the fixture and then use this object in my test file, I would like to get the picklist with the relevant functions.

Here's the basic code example:

```
fixture.js:
const base = require('@playwright/test');
const SettingsPage = require('./settings-page');

exports.test = base.test.extend({
settingsPage: async ({ page }, use) => {
await use(new SettingsPage(page));
  },
});
exports.expect = base.expect;


test.js
const { test, expect } = require('./fixture');

test('basic test', async ({ settingsPage }) => {
const settingToEnable = await settingsPage.setSetting('enabled');
await expect(settingToEnable).toBeEnabled();
});
```

When working in test.js file, I would like to get the settingsPage properties when hovering over it. Also, when entering '.' after settingsPage, I'd like to get the picklist with the functions and properties contained within this page. Instead, I get 'unknown' when hovering over the settingsPage and 'any' - over setSetting function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved your issue but for anyone who comes here and has the same issue your probably just missing:

```
   /**
   * @param {import('@playwright/test').Page} page
   */
```

Once you add that to your classes the auto complete will begin to work. Documentation can be found here: https://playwright.dev/docs/pom. Note the page object class needs the param line of code for auto complete to work.